# AndroidStudio/GoogleMapv2: Array of LatLng/Multiple Latlng To Make A Route

Tags: json, google-maps, android-studio

I know routing is an old topic but all tutorials for Multiple LatLng to a Route following the roads are not working anymore, due from obsolete package of V1 and the new V3 I don't know where to start to code a Jeepney Route anymore. Im having this problem for a week now and my thesis is coming.

Anybody could help me explain further about this code from Neonigma?

```js
private ArrayList<LatLng> getPolylines(String jsonStr) {
    // file exists, it is the first boot
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        // linea init
        LatLng polyline;

        // array list of lines init
        ArrayList<LatLng> polylines = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // get json array
        JSONArray jsonArray = JSON.getJSONArray(jsonStr, "polytag");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonPolyline;

            try {
                jsonPolyline = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                polyline = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(jsonPolyline.getString("lat")),
                        Double.valueOf(jsonPolyline.getString("lon")));

                polylines.add(polyline);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "JSONException reading polylines: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception reading polylines: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return polylines;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The code seems to run for an array of LatLng but I don't know how to fill the missing codes. I am aiming to build multiple coordinates to become a road map through Google Maps. Can anybody help me?

Comment: It looks like this method is parsing a JSON response of some web service and constructs the ArrayList that can be used in the Android API v2 to draw a polyline.

Comment: Yes, it is. Im trying to fit his code to mine. This code doesn't abuse method limit. Im using manual polymarkers coz i don't have time now.